# Which encoding should I use if I want to avoid the presence of certain ascii delimiters with low cost, and can be partially done?

Tags: rust, encoding, tcp, stream, rust-tokio

I am writing a chat server using rust tokio-util Framed, each message between clients and server is in the form of below.

```
command#arg1,arg2,arg3|content$
```

Without any encoding, message cannot be correctly encoded/decoded, for example

```
SendMsg#,receiver,|hello,$world$
```

will be decoded as

```
SendMsg#,receiver,|hello,$
-> 
Message { 
    command: Command::SendMsg, 
    receiver: "receiver".into(), 
    content: Content::Text("hello,".into())
    // snip
}
```

In cases like receiving large files, bytes are read, consumed, then dropped before next iteration of Tcp read to avoid RAM usage. Therefore I cannot use something like `base64`.

```
H -> SA==
I -> SQ==
HI -> SEk=
"SA==SQ==" != "SEK="
```

I barely know about encoding, and I wonder if there exist one satisfies my demand.
If not, I hope to know alternative way of doing this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Often in such cases we encode the string normally, but we precede it by the length of the string: so no problem with special characters or with escaping, and you know how large you need the read buffer. -- Else, just use an other character, e.g. ~ and give e.g. `~~` -> `~`, `~1` -> `,`,  `~2` -> `|`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to close my question, but it should be closed because it is quite stupid.
I should have included a content length as one of the parameter instead of asking for encoding as a way out.
The final version of my serialized `Message` is 'Command#content-length, sender, receiver, filename|content$'. And I adapt my decoder to read `content-length` bytes from the next byte of `|`, check if it is $ after all as verification.

Comment: You can't close question yourself, but you can delete it.